# AngularJS <li> Triggering Modal Box

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have am using bootstrap 3.2.0v and trying to trigger a modal box on click of a listed item in an unordered list. The screen darkens but the modal box does not seem to appear in the window. Both components appear in the DOM when I inspect the element.

Only the background becomes darker.

I have included bootstrap.js and also bootstrap.css.

I have the following code:

```
<li class ng-repeat="type in types" ng-click="changeStatus(type, result.name, result)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#stat">
```

The following for the Modal box:

```
<!-- Modal Box -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="stat" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Ideas?

Furthermore, triggering:

```
  $('#stat').modal('show')
```

shows the correct DOM element (Modal Box) being triggered. But nothing shows on the page, just the screen darkens for each call.

Comment: I recommend just using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I am not quite sure that the Modal would be affected by AngularJS. I am just placing the modal box inside of a ng-repeat but there doesn't seem to be any special dependency on the result.